# How to ls --ignore on osx

Tags: macos, bash, ls

I'm trying to do the following on OSX:

`ls -lR --ignore *.app`

So that I can recursively search through all folders *except* for .app folders.

However it seems there is seems to be no `--ignore` or `--hide` options in Darwin.

Perhaps a script to recursively search one folder deep for a given set and I'm not sure I cant pipe `ls -lR` through anything because of the format of the output:

```
./ROOT/Applications/Some_app:
drwxr-xr-x   3 admin  root  102 26 Jun 11:03 app-bundle.app  #<- WANT THIS
drwxr-xr-x@ 24 admin  root  816 26 Jun 11:24 folder          #<- WANT THIS

./ROOT/Applications/Some_app/app-bundle.app:                 #<- DON'T WANT
drwxr-xr-x  7 admin  root  238 26 Jun 11:03 Contents         #<- DON'T WANT
...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `find`:

```
find . -ls -name '*.app' -prune
```

Comment: find!! _hangs head in shame_ works like a charm. Thank-you (waiting for answer delay)

Comment: your second iteration is much better.

Comment: Thought about it some more, and it can be done even more simply. Always -ls. If it's an app, -prune.

Comment: `find . -ls -name '*.app' -prune | sed -n 's/^[0-9]* *[0-9]* //p'` is perfect!

Comment: After playing with this for a while you just need to be sure to leave the final `/` off your search path

Comment: Nine times out of ten I can also just pipe `find . -ls` to `grep` or `grep -v` when I'm feeling lazy though. But I should get better at using `-prune` and piping to `sed` for more complex stuff. Thanks @RobNapier and @hoss...

Answer (score 5):

In bash, you can use extended globbing to exclude a pattern.

```
shopt -s extglob # this must be on its own line
echo !(*.app) # match everything except for the given pattern
```

If you have bash version 4 or higher, you can use globstar to do this recursively.

```
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s extglob 
echo **/!(*.app)
```

Comment: @hoss - only on bash v4 or higher, using globstar. Added to the answer

Comment: That's a very nice and elegant solution.

Comment: Indeed, very elegant.

Comment: osx 10.8.5 has bash --version = 3.2.48.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to pipe to grep:

ls | grep -v

Comment: not sure this would solve the question at hand of not wanting to traverse into the .app directories in a recursive listing. If I used `ls -R | grep -v ".app"` I end up with *all* files *except* for the .app directory but including all child files and folders.

Comment: This won't work if the terminal is wide and the filenames are short -- it will exclude lots of files not matching the pattern.

Comment: Actually this can be salvaged -- use `1` option to `ls` to force one file per line